# How to stop text wrap and vertically center text in sliding div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div that slides out from a picture, but I'd like to center the text in this div vertically and have it not wrap or rather unwrap as the div expands/slides out. I still want it to stay within the div and not overflow.

Here is my fiddle and css:

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnWeb/rBsLx/21/

```
.textbox
{
    max-width: 610px;
    height: 155px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-wrap: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(5, 58, 24, 0.65) 10%,rgba(0,0,0,0.13) 93%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.textbox p
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-wrap:  none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a width to the paragraph inside that `<div>` for instance, else it will only take 100% actual width of its parent. example at : http://jsfiddle.net/rBsLx/22/

```
.textbox p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 610px;
}
```

I setted `610px`, since it is the `max-width` you give to that `<div>`